# Get crossed probability of an exel table in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, probability

I have an Excel table (200x780). The lines are options available on an aircraft, and the columns are serial numbers. The content is either `1` or `0`, depending on if the aircraft has or not the option.

Matrix:

[image]

I want a table with the options as line and column, containing the probability of having two options together. Something like this, matrix probability:

[image]

I used `pandas.read_excel` to read the file, and thought about multiplying each line with the others, but this will take a lot of time. Is there a panda module I didn't find that can do this easier?

Comment: Please include a proper dataset(or a part) and what output you desire.

Comment: I don't understand what more I can give about the dataset, over the picture?

Comment: include atleast 10rowsX10 columns as input and also the desired output for the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @jezrael there is no code!

Comment: @Ivan - You are right, but I think in links is writtten it - code is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Excel very easily.

If `Data` represents the 200 rows by 780 columns of input data then the array formula

```
=MMULT(Data,TRANSPOSE(Data))/780
```

gives you a 200 row by 200 column matrix of values in which the (i,j)'th element (row i and column j) is obtained from the i'th and j'th rows of the input `Data`.

Select the 200*200 range of cells where you want the output to appear, enter the formula into the formula bar and commit using the Ctrl, Shift and Enter keys pressed simultaneously. You can substitute a range such as `B2:ADA201` for `Data` in the formula.

Comment: The problem is I need to use Python, it is the requirement. But I'm working on reformulating the question better.

Comment: If you have a matrix multiplication library available then you could use that: multiply your data matrix by its transpose to get a 200*200 matrix then divide every element by 780.

Comment: I tried using 'df.as_matrix' , then 'df2 = df1.transpose' , but when I try multiplying df1 and df2, there is the error : '_with block values unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'long' and 'instancemethod'_

Comment: Sorry, can't help further as I don't know anything about Python or the features you are trying to  use. However, from a mathematical perspective matrix multiplication fits with what you are trying to do. Matrix multiplication is different from normal multiplication so perhaps you need to seek out the appropriate method for matrix multiplication.